# Bower: How to patch a package or apply overrides?

Tags: javascript, bower

Which is the best way to override or apply patches on a package, that is added to my project by using bower?

In my Sass folder I have a vendor_overrides folder, I'm ok with that, but how to handle javascripts?

Fork the project and then install that with bower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anyway to do this with bower.

Like you suggested. Fork and hosting your own is an option. It is mentioned in [What's a good method for monkey patching Bower packages in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25435329/27604)

Another method, Which I ended up going with since I was just making a small change was to create a patch file using `diff original_file modified_file > patch_file` and then patch that file using `patch -N file < patch_file`.

Then I just make sure that in the tool chain for setting up/ building the project that that patch call occurs after `bower install`