# What's a good method for monkey patching Bower packages in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, monkeypatching

I'm working on an Angular.js project based on [ngBoilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp). I had some environment specific issues that had to be resolved by adding a couple lines to the Angular source. I've got some other teammates who may work on this project, so I want to make sure that when they clone down the repo locally and Bower install, Angular works for them as well. What's a good method for monkey patching my fixes into the app to ensure they'll be available for others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fork the Angular repo, modify it, and use your own copy as your bower dependency. Be sure to document how your fork differs from the original angular source.

Or, look for a way to resolve the issues with the stock angular, and distribute the fix as a required script.

Comment: In this case, I'll still have to keep my forked angular up to date with the most recent one, correct?

Comment: Yep. But it is probably a bad idea to update the angular code you're using without also testing and if necessary updating your patched code. So my preference would be to manually update my forked repo instead of hoping that future main-line angular versions work with my standalone patch.

Comment: @mackenco PS i just found this useful guide for how to update your local copy https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork